# Is a signed Android APK-File running on x86- and ARM-Android devices?

Tags: java, android, x86, arm

Android APK-Files are not binaries but byte-code-files. So is it possible to install the same APK-File on both - on x86-Android-Devices and ARM-Android-Devices?
There are some x86-Netbooks with Android installed planned and I wonder if it is possible to run the APK-Files on both kinds of devices?

Best regards,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, these devices will run an x86 version of the dalvik vm so your application will run just fine with respects to the application itself, it may not run if it needs stuff like GPS,or other cellphone based classes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Android APK files are really ZIP archives.  They contain the XML, art files, Java and binary (native) code.  If your app is written entirely in Java then it will work on whatever CPU Android is running on.  If you have cpu-specific binary code (e.g. generated with the NDK), then it will only run on the target cpu.
L.B.